# Can't delete AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I accidentally created an instance of `AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse` with a bad value - `DEFAULT_400` instead of `DEFAULT_4XX`. The instance got created, or at least "partially created", although the Cloudformation stack in which it was contained returned an error. Now I can't delete it - every time I try I get

```
 1 validation error detected: Value 'DEFAULT_400' at 'responseType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [REQUEST_TOO_LARGE, RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, AUTHORIZER_CONFIGURATION_ERROR, {...}]
```

How can I force deletion of this instance, ideally via the AWS CLI ?

PS it appears to have been "orphaned", ie the parent `RestApi` it belonged to has been deleted

Comment: You could try creating the exact same resource that CF is trying to create (but with different parameters) and CF might detect that it created the one it wanted to create

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of deleting stacks which can be automatically removed. They are listed in AWS docs:

- [How do I delete an AWS CloudFormation stack that's stuck in DELETE_FAILED status?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-delete-failed/)

Comment: Console deletion didn't work :( Working with AWS support to try and get it removed :/